# Python argv validation

Tags: python, validation, argv

I need to check if the user is giving the input file and the name of the output, and I'm doing the following:

```
def main():
    if len(argv) > 2:
        script, file_in, file_out = argv
        execute_code(file_in, file_out)
    else:
        print "Wrong number of arguments!"
        print "Usage: python script.py filename_input filename_output"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there other way to check if the `argv` arguments are correct?

Comment: Of course there is. You could try to use them and catch and report any exceptions. You could explicitly check types or duck-type them. What are you really asking?

Comment: I want to know if exists more elegants or correct ways to achieve it.

Comment: My point is "to achieve what?" To validate that the _number of arguments passed_ is correct? Not really. To validate that the arguments are the types of things you expect? Maybe/probably, but it's impossible to tell from your example because no one knows what `execute_code` expects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

> The *argparse* module makes it easy to write user-friendly command-line
>   interfaces. The program defines what arguments it requires, and
>   *argparse* will figure out how to parse those out of *sys.argv*.

For example your `main` function could be rewritten as

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('file_in', help='input file')
    parser.add_argument('file_out', help='output file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    execute_code(args.file_in, args.file_out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`argparse` will perform validation for you and display fairly helpful error messages if some of the required arguments are missing:

```
vaultah@base:~$ python3 /home/vaultah/untitled.py
usage: untitled.py [-h] file_in file_out
untitled.py: error: the following arguments are required: file_in, file_out
vaultah@base:~$ python3 /home/vaultah/untitled.py in
usage: untitled.py [-h] file_in file_out
untitled.py: error: the following arguments are required: file_out
```

Additionally, it will generate a help message

```
vaultah@base:~$ python3 /home/vaultah/untitled.py -h
usage: untitled.py [-h] file_in file_out

positional arguments:
  file_in     input file
  file_out    output file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's a little more work, you might want to consider using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

You code would become:

```
import argparse

def execute_code(file_in, file_out):
    pass

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some files.')
    parser.add_argument('file_in',  help='input file')
    parser.add_argument('file_out',  help='output file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    execute_code(args.file_in, args.file_out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running the program with no arguments:
`python demo.py`

Yields:

```
usage: demo.py [-h] file_in file_out
demo.py: error: the following arguments are required: file_in, file_out
```

Running the program with the `-h` flag:

`python demo.py -h`

Yields:

```
usage: demo.py [-h] file_in file_out

Process some files.

positional arguments:
  file_in     input file
  file_out    output file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Use argparse; ideally, use [argparse.FileType](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) to open files automatically from command-line arguments.

If the arguments don't make sense as open files, you can catch the exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the option required=True to make the arguments mandatory. This will throw an error if the required arguments are not specified. Here is an example:

```
parser.add_argument("--required_arg",
                    required=True,
                    help="The argument which is mandatory")
```

For checking the path of the input and output files, you can use the following code:

```
 if not os.path.exists(file_name):
    error_message =  file_name + " does not exist \n";
```

You can also look at [my blog Techable](https://bhavaniabtechie.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/python-parsing-arguments-through-argparse/) for more information on argument parser in python.